# Regular Expression match for text after numbers

Tags: regex, match

I'm looking for a way to match the following:

**Test Strings:**

*Scenario 1:* "Validate: 1: Bad address. Do you want to proceed?" (without quotes)
*Scenario 2:* "Validate: 1: Bad payment type2: Invalid credit card number." (without quotes)
*Scenario 3:* "Validate: 1: Bad payment type2: Invalid credit card number.3: Invalid Expiration Date." (without quotes)

There will always be Validate before the first number:, after that is text with possible special characters including "'()#,.? If there are more than one issue that is added directly after that last character of the previous message.

**Extracting:**

*Scenario 1:* "Bad address. Do you want to proceed?"
*Scenario 2:* "Bad payment type","Invalid credit card number."
*Scenario 3:* "Bad payment type","Invalid credit card number.","Invalid Expiration Date."

More or less anything between or after the "##: ", I want to extract. I won't always know what is contained.  I'm using Coldfusion which is Java at its heart. But I can do the conversion between most languages (php,CF,c#,Java, etc) regex.

I've thought about doing something like this:

```
(\d+)(.)(\s+)
```

to find the positions to extract the text but figured if someone could come up with a more graceful solution I would use it.

Comment: What makes you think that regular expressions are the right tool for this job?

Comment: Do you have predefined Strings to extract ? you might want to try `mystring.contains("Bad payment type")`

Comment: @VinayBhargav I do, but there are possibly hundreds if not more validation issues.

Comment: @Sneftel I'm shooting in the dark. If you have a better suggestion I'm all ears.

Comment: your question is incomplete .. you have to mention all possible cases for inputs and your desired ouputs (you don't need to list all of them, try to explain in words) .. unless you do this, no one can help you

Comment: @twalberti, you really need to specify your language/dev environment.

Comment: @zespri How much clearer can one get "**I'm using Coldfusion which is Java at its heart."**

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `sed`, the following will do it:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*[0-9]: \(.*\)/\1/' | sed 's/[0-9]//g'
```